# Flutter: Google Sign-In API Exception 10

Tags: flutter, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am having some trouble integrating Google Sign-In into my Flutter app. I am using [google_sign_in 6.2.1](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in), and have been struggling to resolve this error for about a week now.

I have spent countless hours searching for help all over Google, StackOverflow, and other forums, but am completely out of answers at this point. I came across various similar issues dealing with the same error, but none of the listed solutions have worked for me.

Here is the error in question:
**PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)**

Here is a list of everything that I have tried thus far (to no success):

- Validated SHA-1 / SHA-256 keys
- Quadruple-checked both release AND debug SHA-1/SHA-256 keys on Firebase & Cloud Console
- Verified google-services.json
- Verified no API key restrictions on Cloud Console
- Verified OAuth 2.0 Client IDs
- Verified plugins in android/build.gradle
- Verified classpaths in android/app/build.gradle
- Verified permissions AndroidManifest.xml
- Added a support email into Firebase / Cloud Console
- Enabled Google Sign-In on Firebase
- Regenerated the keys
- Inserted SHA1 keys from the .keystore files
- Inserted SHA1 keys from .\gradlew signingReport
- Downloaded and updated google-services.json
- Cleaned + Rebuilt after any and all changes made
- Run on various build flavors (debug, profile, release)
- Run on various devices and simulators

If anyone has any suggestions on how to proceed, it would mean a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.